# Make img rotate when hovering over img, other img and h2

Tags: css, wordpress

I need an image to rotate 180° When hovering that image but also hovering an other image and an h2 should make the first image rotate

I tried multiple codes, pure css but also css and jquery

so with the css code below I made the first image rotate

```css
.circle_img{  
  position: absolute;
  margin-top:-10px;
}
.circle_img:hover {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<img class="circle_img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
```

So I am kinda stuck here :(
I gave the other img and h2 a class named img-rotate,
but now I don't know how to continue

Thanks in advance

Comment: please, show a full example with the minimal code necessary to see the issue

Comment: you need to add a [transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions) on the transform

Comment: I forgot to mention that it is done in wordpress using divi

Answer (score 1):

Add `transition: 1s ease all;` to your code.

```css
.circle_img{  
  position: absolute;
  margin-top:-10px;
  transition: 1s ease all;
}
.circle_img:hover {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<img class="circle_img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
```

Comment: That indeed made it rotate the way I wanted :) But now I have to make it rotate when I hover other elements as well :(